# Para que serve o "await" no Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gostaria de saber o que é e para que serve o `await` no Python.

Tem algo a ver com *threads*?

Comment: Em C# seria um comando para aguardar a tarefa da Task(nova thread). Acho que seria o mesmo esquema.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

O `await` em Python é usado de forma que fica parecendo um prefixo para uma chamada de função que será uma chamada assíncrona.

Assim, começando pelo final - o que vemos no código e o seu efeito, e depois entendendo o que de fato acontece. Pode ser que você encontre código que seja dessa forma:

```
async def uma_funcao():
    # algum código preparatório
    ...
    resultado = await outra_funcao(valores)
    # algumas linhas de código usando o resultado acima 
    ...
    return valor
```

O que acontece aí é que se a `outra_funcao` for demorada, o seu código vai sofrer uma "pausa" nesse ponto, e depois continuar na linha de baixo, como se nada tivesse acontecido.  Pera - mas não é o que aconteceria num programa normal, sem o `await`? 
A diferença é que em código desse tipo, enquanto o código da  `uma_funcao` espera pelo resultado da chamada a `outra_funcao`, o programa **não para** . Outras funções e outro código declarado como "assíncrono" continua executando.

Então, o `await` e outras palavras chave (como o `async def` também presente no exemplo acima), foram incluidas na linguagem para facilitar o uso dessa abordagem de programação chamada "assíncrona". (Programação assíncrona já era possível antes do uso dessas palavras chave, no Python 3.5, mas a coisa era feita meio manualmente).
A programação assíncrona, por sua vez, permite que um dado programa faça mais de uma coisa "aparentemente" ao mesmo tempo - isso é, em um dado instante, pode haver mais de uma função do código do programa sendo executada - e nisso, ela é semelhante a programação multi-threaded.

Quando se usa multi-threading, no entanto, há algumas diferenças: as threads podem (embora não seja a regra em Python), usar mais de um núcleo físico do processador, e serem executadas "de fato" ao mesmo tempo. Em programação assíncrona, toda a ação acontece em **uma única** thread do sistema (e portanto, um único núcleo da CPU). As chamadas a função prefixadas com `await` (e alguns comandos prefixados com `async`, tais como `async for`  e `async with`)  causam uma "pausa" na função que está rodando - e o controle da execução é passado para uma função de controle - em geral chamamos de "loop" (laço) de controle do sistema assíncrono. Esse "loop" é que gerencia a interrupção e continuidade de várias funções que fazem pausas.

Para dar um exemplo bem concreto, de um restaurante: um garçom funcionando com código "síncrono" normal: ele iria até a mesa, pegaria o pedido do cliente, vai até a cozinha, entrega o pedido e *espera* parado até o pedido ficar pronto. Quando está pronto, leva o pedido até a mesa original e só aí vai atender outras mesas.

O garçom "multi-threading" faz exatamente a mesma coisa - só que o restaurante tem mais  de um garçom. Então se o restaurante tem 10 mesas ocupadas e 5 garçons, as 5 primeiras mesas nem vão perceber - chamam um garçom, ele vem, e alguns minutos depois volta com o pedido pronto. O cliente da sexta mesa vai ver 5 garçons parados na cozinha enquanto quer fazer o pedido, e pode ficar chateado.

O garçom "assíncrono": vai até a mesa, tira o pedido, vai até a cozinha, entrega a comanda do pedido - isso é equivalente ao "await". Volta ao salão, atende outras mesas, e, eventualmente, quando for até a cozinha (ou for chamado pela campainha), pega o resultado do pedido original e leva até aquela mesa. Pra quem estava na mesa, o processo todo levou o mesmo tempo, mas o garçom pode atender várias outras mesas enquanto o pedido era preparado.

Uma das principais vantagens nessa abordagem é que você, ao escrever a função assíncrona, sabe *exatamente* em que ponto o código da sua função vai ser "pausado" e outro código vai rodar - então se o seu programa está usando estruturas de dados compartilhadas (tais como listas ou dicionários), sabe que se entre duas linhas de seu código não há nenhuma chamada "async", nenhuma outra parte do código foi executada, e portanto suas estruturas de dados não foram alteradas por outras funções. Isso faz com que código assíncrono não precise fazer uso das `lock`s e `mutexes` usadas em código multi-threaded (via de regra). Outra vantagem é que não há gasto de recursos de troca de thread para passagem de dados entre duas tarefas diferentes.

O importante ao se pensar em escrever código com essa abordagem no entanto é saber que só é possível ter ganhos reais se você tiver alguma função que seria "bloqueante" - por exemplo, uma chamada que vai fazer um request a uma API remota, ou requisitar uma query demorado a um banco de dados -  essa chamada deve ela mesma ser dentro de uma função assíncrona (função que tem o `async def` em vez de somente `def`) , então o laço principal vai ser capaz de executar mais código enquanto o resultado da função demorada não chega. No caso de acesso a banco, ou ao sistema de arquivos, é necessário que o próprio driver do Python seja assíncrono (ou seja, para usar o postgresql, você vai se conectar ao banco com o "asyncpg", não com o popular "psycopg2", para poder ter benefícios de programação assíncrona.

Via de regra esse tipo de código faz mais sentido em programas que vão funcionar como servidores (incluindo aplicações WEB), atendendo vários clientes ao mesmo tempo: enquanto uma requisição está sendo processada, se encontra uma chamada demorada para reunir os dados necessários para a resposta, outras requisições podem ser processadas em paralelo. Mas é possível pensar em escrever o núcleo principal de um jogo em que os vários agentes são coordenados através de funções assíncronas também.

Por outro lado, justamente por que esse tipo de código só começa a valer  a pena em aplicações complexas, é muito difícil achar um exemplo concreto e pequeno. A documentação incluí um "hello world" - tudo o que ele usa é uma função "sleep" assíncrona que faz a resposta demorar um pouco mais -

```
import asyncio

async def say(what, when):
    await asyncio.sleep(when)
    print(what)
    if when == 5:
       loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
       loop.stop()

loop =  asyncio.new_event_loop()
for i in range(5, -1, -1):
    loop.create_task(say(f'hello world {i}', i))
    print(f"co-rotina {i} criada")
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

(baseada no exemplo em em http://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hello_world.html)

Então resumindo o que acontece aí: a linguagem Python tem uma implementação bem completa do tal "laço de orquestração" na biblioteca `asyncio`. Nada impede que você implemente seu próprio laço para fazer uso das mesmas palavras chave.

A chamada `loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()` pega uma referência para um novo laço de coordenação. A chamada `loop.create_task(say('hello world', 1))` adiciona à "lista de tarefas que estão sendo executadas" no laço essa chamada à função `say`.

Perceba que diferente de quando passamos uma função para ser executada numa thread separada, em que passamos o nome da função (sem os `( )` para chamar a função) e os argumentos separadamente, a chamada a  `run_until_complete` chama a função `say` : `say('hello world', 1)`. O que acontece é que como ela foi definida com `async def` ela não é executada nesse momento - ela só é preparada, e o Python cria um objeto do tipo "co-rotina" . Essa "co-rotina" que é colocada na lista de tarefas do laço - e aí ele "se vira" pra orquestrar as chamadas e resultados reais.

Quem programa as funções não precisa se preocupar em ficar verificando resultados de `futures`  ou o que fazer se uma exceção acontece dentro de uma chamada assíncrona - o loop principal do evento manda as exceções para o ponto certo no programa.

Então se você colar o código acima no interpretador interativo vai ver pelos prints que todas as tarefas são criadas ao mesmo tempo - mas cada uma "dorme" um número diferente de segundos - e os resultados vão chegando um por segundo. Se você fizer o codigo equivalente usando  `time.sleep`, cada função vai parar `when` segundos, antes de continuar - depois de imprimir "4", o programa esperaria 5 segundos inteiros pela próxima resposta.

Comment: Não fico muito claro uma coisa, para usar o `await` no Python, é **necessário** estar dentro de uma função assíncrona  (`async def...`) como no javascript?

Comment: sim, é. Sem estar numa função assíncrona, não existe um loop externo que pode assumir o controle quando o await é usado.